# Is it correct to say "When is the video?"?

Tags: wh-questions

*The video is of 2020.*

Can I make question of above sentence in this manner: *When was the video?* Or *When was?* Or *When is this video?*

I found the first line [here](https://factonews.co/media-outlets-share-old-video-as-russian-fighter-jets-invading-ukraines-airbases/).

Similarly, if my friend tells me some past news then can I ask, *When was this news?* Or *When was this news of?*

If I see some video circulating on social media, Can I ask *When was this?*? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There are several errors here. Here are some corrections and suggestions. Questions using when generally need a verb of some kind, or they will sound incomplete, and won't make sense. There are a few exceptions to this, like when asking about events in history.

> The video is from 2020.

You could ask

> When was this video made?
>
> When was this video created?
>
> when was this video posted (or published)?
>
> On what date was this video posted?

For news, you could ask

> When was this news reported?
>
> When was this news published?
>
> On what date was this news reported?

Comment: Or can I say just, "When is the video from?"

Comment: @ramanujan Yes you could, but it's quite informal/colloquial - putting a preposition at the end of a sentence could lose you marks in an exam.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find *This video is of 2020* on the page you link to, so I assume it has since been edited.

It would be more natural to say *This video was made/filmed in 2020* or *it dates from 2020*.

You need to ask *either* when the video was made *or* when the events shown in it happened.

*News* is, by definition, a report of something that has happened recently. You could ask 'When did this [event] happen?' or 'When was the news announced?'

Comment: The line is still there on that link. The complete sentence is *He has also stated that the video is of 2020 of a  parade rehearsal over Tushino, Moscow.* Can I post screenshot here? The line is on 8th paragraph just above the *Batman* tweet.

Comment: Found it. This is an error on the writer's part (and I notice that the person quoted didn't actually say that in his tweet). _The video is from 2020, of a parade rehearsal_ would be better.